# Is it ok to have lots of sites in IIS?

Tags: iis, subdomain, website

My website dynamically creates sub-domains for clients that sign up with us. Our current set up in IIS is a bunch of sites (around 40) that have bindings for many sub-domains (it can be up to 100 sub-domains). So What I'm wondering is, is it better to have one site per sub-domain, or should it be fewer sites that have a bunch of bindings per sub-domain? When I say many sub-domains, I'm mean in the thousands.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider things like:

1. Host header and URL needs, how do you want to present your sites to the world?
2. SSL Binding, does your sites needs any?
3. Available IPs/NICs for binding and performance improvement.
4. Application level control, example: do you need to have different app pools?

Eventually, if you run all your apps into different sites, you'll have more control on the application level for each site, But if you don't need that and would like to keep things simpler to edit in the future (think config files and app pools), perhaps a subsite is a better idea.